# Mongo Update Only Affecting 1st Element in Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a Mongo updateMany() query.

A condensed example of a document in my collection:

```
{
    "CurrentVersion": 3,
    "EntryHistory": [
        {
            "State": 0,
            "ProposalPlan": [
                {
                    "Description": "Test",
                    "State": 1,
                    "Proposals": [
                        {
                            "Subject": "Test",
                            "Body": "Test",
                            "Urls": [
                                {
                                    "Description": "Link text",
                                    "Address": "https://examplelink.com"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please assume that my test data is just showing structure and not the actual size of the collection and the arrays.

How can I write my updateMany() query to affect all elements in EntryHistory for every document where EntryHistory.$.ProposalPlan.State is equal to 1?

Here is the query I wrote:

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
    { "EntryHistory.ProposalPlan.State": 1 },
    { $set: {
                "EntryHistory.$.ProposalPlan.State": 3,
                "EntryHistory.$.ProposalPlan.Proposals.10.Urls.0.Address": "https://newlinkexample.com"
            }
    }
);
```

My intention with this query is, for every document and subsequently every element in EntryHistory for which EntryHistory.$.ProposalPlan.State is equal to 1, to update the values as specified in the update statement.

The problem is that I am testing my query on test data for which I know there are multiple documents and, for most documents, multiple elements in their respective EntryHistory arrays for which ProposalPlan.State is equal to 1, but for each of these documents in the collection, the update is only applied to the first element in EntryHistory which meets the criteria. Any element in EntryHistory where ProposalPlan.State is equal to 1 is only updated if it's the first occurrence in the EntryHistory array. It will update every document needing to be updated, but not every relevant element in the respective EntryHistory arrays, which is my intention.

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) states that this (the positional operator updating only the first matching entry in the array) is expected behavior. Therefore your options are probably to run the update multiple times or to [use array filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can do the trick unless you have more nested levels (mongoDB 4.2+) :

```
db.collection.update({},
[
{
 $set: {
  "EntryHistory": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$EntryHistory",
      "as": "e",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$e",
          {
            "ProposalPlan": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$e.ProposalPlan",
                "as": "p",
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$p",
                    {
                      "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$p.State",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "then": {
                          State: 3,
                          Proposals: {
                            "$map": {
                              "input": "$$p.Proposals",
                              "as": "r",
                              "in": {
                                "$mergeObjects": [
                                  "$$r",
                                  {
                                    "$cond": {
                                      "if": {
                                        "$eq": [
                                          {
                                            "$indexOfArray": [
                                              "$$p.Proposals",
                                              "$$r"
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          0 // Index of Proposals
                                          
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      "then": {
                                        "Urls": {
                                          "$map": {
                                            "input": "$$r.Urls",
                                            "as": "u",
                                            "in": {
                                              "$mergeObjects": [
                                                "$$u",
                                                {
                                                  "$cond": {
                                                    "if": {
                                                      "$eq": [
                                                        {
                                                          "$indexOfArray": [
                                                            "$$r.Urls",
                                                            "$$u"
                                                          ]
                                                        },
                                                        2 // Index of Urls
                                                        
                                                      ]
                                                    },
                                                    "then": {
                                                      Address: "Example new link"
                                                    },
                                                    "else": {}
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "else": {}
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "else": {}
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
          ]
         }
        }
      }
     }
   }
 ])
```

Explained:

Use update/aggreagation/$map/$cond/$indexOfArray to update only necessary Urls.
In the example update EntryHistory array where State=1 with State=3
, in entryHistory where State is updated from 1 to 3 update Proposals array element with index=0  and update only Address for urls with index=2

pseudo code:

update({},{EntryHistory.$.ProposalPlan.$["State=1"].Proposals.0.Urls.2.Address="Example new link"})

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5toGRHkNx6O)

---

**Option 2: ( ArrayFilters option ) **

```
db.collection.update({
 "EntryHistory.ProposalPlan.State": 1,

},
{
 $set: {
  "EntryHistory.$[].ProposalPlan.$[x].State": 3,
```

"EntryHistory.$[].ProposalPlan.$[x].Proposals.$[].Urls.$[].Address": "NewAddress"
},

```
 },
 {
   "arrayFilters": [
 {
     "x.State": 1
  }
  ],
    multi: true
  })
```

Explained:
Is not very clear but perhaps this is what you need to update all Addresses for ProposalPlan.state=1.

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F5rMomiA_JX)