# Mongo Update Array & Skip Null Fields

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a Mongo updateMany() query.

A condensed example of a document in my collection:

```
{
    "CurrentVersion": 3,
    "EntryHistory": [
        {
            "State": 0,
            "ProposalPlan": [
                {
                    "Description": "Test",
                    "State": 1,
                    "Proposals": [
                        {
                            "Subject": "Test",
                            "Body": "Test",
                            "Urls": [
                                {
                                    "Description": "Link text",
                                    "Address": "https://examplelink.com"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please assume that my test data is just showing structure and not the actual size of the collection and the arrays.

How can I write my updateMany() query to not error out if it encounters a null field in a document? I just want it to continue with updating documents if one is problematic.

Here is the query I wrote:

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
    { "ProposalPlan.State": 1 },
    {
        $set: {
            "ProposalPlan.State": 3,
            "ProposalPlan.Proposals.10.Urls.0.Address": "https://newlinkexample.com"
        }
    }
);
```

My problem is that when I run this query, some documents that meet the filter criteria are "corrupt" and have null or nonexistent Proposals and/or null or nonexistent Urls, so I am faced with an error such as "MongoServerError: Cannot create field '0' in element {Urls: null}".

I have also tried wrapping the above query in a try catch, as I expected it to continue after a document throws an error, but I see that's not how it works.

I tried to add to the filters so that I am not even trying to update the corrupt documents to begin with:

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
    { "ProposalPlan.State": 1, "ProposalPlan.Proposals.10.Urls.0.Address": { $ne: null } },
    {
        $set: {
            "ProposalPlan.State": 3,
            "ProposalPlan.Proposals.10.Urls.0.Address": "https://newlinkexample.com"
        }
    }
);
```

But none of this has worked so far. The above extra filter does not throw an error but nothing is updated, and when I try to use the filters with findOne() it just searches infinitely rather than grabbing one of the many records where ProposalPlan.State is 1 and ProposalPlan.Proposals.10.Urls.0.Address is not null.

Comment: it looks very much to your previous question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774189/mongo-update-only-affecting-1st-element-in-array

Comment: @R2D2 In my previous question I was asking how to apply an update to all elements in the array - that was for a different query. I am now asking how I can write a different update query that will not fail when fields are null. Different question and different query, though the same collection. I reused the question body as needed to exemplify my collection.

Comment: please , check option 2 in my answer , I think this is what you need,?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Option 1(+4.2 aggregation framework):**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
 {
  $set: {
  "EntryHistory": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$EntryHistory",
      "as": "e",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$e",
          {
            "ProposalPlan": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$e.ProposalPlan",
                "as": "p",
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$p",
                    {
                      "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$p.State",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "then": {
                          State: 3,
                          Proposals: {
                            "$map": {
                              "input": "$$p.Proposals",
                              "as": "r",
                              "in": {
                                "$mergeObjects": [
                                  "$$r",
                                  {
                                    "$cond": {
                                      "if": {
                                        "$eq": [
                                          {
                                            "$indexOfArray": [
                                              "$$p.Proposals",
                                              "$$r"
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          0// Index of Proposals
                                          
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      "then": {
                                        "Urls": {
                                          "$map": {
                                            "input": "$$r.Urls",
                                            "as": "u",
                                            "in": {
                                              "$mergeObjects": [
                                                "$$u",
                                                {
                                                  "$cond": {
                                                    "if": {
                                                      $and: [
                                                        {
                                                          "$eq": [
                                                            {
                                                              "$indexOfArray": [
                                                                "$$r.Urls",
                                                                "$$u"
                                                              ]
                                                            },
                                                            2// Index of Urls
                                                            
                                                          ]
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                          "$ne": [
                                                            "$$u.Address",
                                                            null
                                                          ]
                                                        }
                                                      ]
                                                    },
                                                    "then": {
                                                      Address: "Example new link"
                                                    },
                                                    "else": {}
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "else": {}
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "else": {}
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
          ]
         }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ])
```

Explained:

It will update:

```
        "ProposalPlan.State": 3,
        "ProposalPlan.Proposals.0.Urls.2.Address": "new value"
```

( changed Peoposals.10 with 0 since example become too big ...)

But if( "ProposalPlan.Proposals.0.Urls.2.Address"== null)
Then it will update only:

```
        "ProposalPlan.State": 3
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5P70F-OcWD7)

---

**Option 2 ( arrayFilter ) - maybe this is the exact one you need**

```
db.collection.update({
 "EntryHistory.ProposalPlan.State": 1,
 "EntryHistory.ProposalPlan.Proposals.Urls.Address": {
  $ne: null
}
},
{
 $set: {
  "EntryHistory.$[].ProposalPlan.$[x].State": 3,
  "EntryHistory.$[].ProposalPlan.$[x].Proposals.0.Urls.2.Address": "NewAddress"
 },

},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
   {
     "x.State": 1
  }
 ],
  multi: true
 })
```

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pG-aqH1Qd4C)

Explained:

Using arrayFilters match the ProposalPlan with State=1 and update from Proposal[0] documents where Urls[2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pG-aqH1Qd4C) Address value is not null